# move record to different column and row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i have problem with moving the record into another column and row from table that have thousands records and i need to move it simultaneously. for example, i have this kind of table

```
data <- read.table(text="C1 C2 C3 
1   2  3 
a   b  c 
4   5  6 
d   e  f 
7   8  9 
g   h  i
10 11 12
j   k  l",stringsAsFactors=F,header=T)

C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
1   2  3
a   b  c 
4   5  6 
d   e  f 
7   8  9 
g   h  i
10 11 12
j   k  l
```

i need to move the 2nd, 4th, 6th and so on record to C4 C5 and C6 column. this could be what it looks like

```
C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
1   2  3  a  b  c 
4   5  6  d  e  f 
7   8  9  g  h  i
10 11 12  j  k  l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your desired output is always following a separated even and odd row pattern,

```
data <- data[,1:3] # I added this line since I did not understand if your data
                   # has 3 or 6 columns at the beginning.

out <- data.frame(data[1:nrow(data)%%2!=0,],
        data[1:nrow(data)%%2==0,])

colnames(out)[4:6] <- c("C4","C5","C6")

out
```

gives,

```
  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
1  1  2  3  a  b  c
3  4  5  6  d  e  f
5  7  8  9  g  h  i
7 10 11 12  j  k  l
```

**Data:**

```
data <- read.table(text="C1 C2 C3 
1   2  3 
a   b  c 
4   5  6 
d   e  f 
7   8  9 
g   h  i
10 11 12
j   k  l",stringsAsFactors=F,header=T)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..
All of the answers are correct. i will check this since you're the first one give me answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is written as is in a flat file, we may use `scan` with `multi.line` to specify that 1 record spreads over 2 lines:

```
names <- scan(f, what = character(), nlines = 1)

data <- scan(
  file = f,
  skip = 1,
  multi.line = TRUE,
  what = list(double(), double(), double(), character(), character(), character())
)

data <- setNames(data, nm = names)

df <- as.data.frame(data)

#>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
#> 1  1  2  3  a  b  c
#> 2  4  5  6  d  e  f
#> 3  7  8  9  g  h  i
#> 4 10 11 12  j  k  l
```

---

Where the data is stored in flat file `f` like so:

```
cat("C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
1   2  3
a   b  c 
4   5  6 
d   e  f 
7   8  9 
g   h  i
10 11 12
j   k  l
", file = f <- tempfile())
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```
# data
d <- read.table(text = "C1 C2 C3
1   2  3
a   b  c 
4   5  6 
d   e  f 
7   8  9 
g   h  i
10 11 12
j   k  l", header = T)

# solution
numbers_df <- d[seq(1, nrow(d), 2), ] # get rows 1, 3, 5, ..
chars_df <- d[seq(2, nrow(d), 2), ] # get rows 2, 4, ..
colnames(chars_df) <- paste0("C", 4:6) # add column names

cbind(numbers_df, chars_df)
```